# Need help installing a DNS on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system

I am trying to configure a DNS for an Ubuntu server.  Initially I had problems pinging the server or doing any kind of dig.  The relevant info up to that point is visible below under "Old Issues".  Through much assistance I have gotten the DNS to respond to a ping request via its IP, and most importantly it is now acknowledging the dig -x 127.0.0.1 command.

These prior issues came about due to an error in my [name server syntax](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIND9ServerHowto) in the Forward Zone File (eg. db.example.com.).

Currently the issue remains that the server can not be called by the example.com.  I can only assume that this is a problem with my reference to the recursive DNS server, however I am unsure of how to fix this.  All help is appreciated.

**Old Issues**
As per requested, below are the results for various ping requests, digs, and what is entered into bind named.config prior to any suggestions.

"ping example.com" times out and outputs:

```
ping: unknown host example.com
```

"ping 1.2.3.4" (net ip) outputs:

```
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 8999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.688/0.960/3.221/0.754 ms
```

"ping 1.2.3.4" (local ip) outputs:

```
PING 192.168.1.68 (192.168.1.68) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.1.68 ping statistics ---
21 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 19999ms
```

"ping 4.2.2.2" outputs:

```
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 32.742/33.081/33.544/0.411 ms
```

bind named.conf file:

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
```

resolv.conf file:
  version 1

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 4.2.2.2
```

version 2

```
search example.com
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 68.238.64.12
```

nslookup google.com

```
Server:         192.168.1.1
Address:        192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.45.100
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.53.100
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.67.100
```

**New Issues**

dig -x 127.0.0.1   this line seems to be of concern, shouldn't these 0's be 1's?

```
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
```

[cat /etc/bind/named.conf.options](http://pastebin.com/m6faff332)

[tail -n 100 /var/log/syslog](http://pastebin.com/m2cf78dc5)

[cat /var/log/syslog | grep bind](http://pastebin.com/m75bd69e5)

named.conf.local

```
zone "example.com"{
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.example.com";
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.233";
};
```

Comment: OK, the new information is useful, but it's still unclear which machines are reporting which problem?  You're asking 127.0.0.1 to be recursive, but is this also the recursive server you're using (per my original response).  Frankly, I'm still none the wiser about your overall network architecture.

Comment: i definitely do not want the server to be recursive.  is this because of the 127.0.0.1 in the resolv.conf file?

Comment: well, if your own server (localhost?) is only authoritative then your resolv.conf should point to your ISPs recursive server, and not 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check you network is UP and running
2. Check you routing and if default rote is installed ( `netstat -rn` )
3. Check internet connection by pinging 4.2.2.2 ( `ping 4.2.2.2` )
4. Check your dns configs ( `cat /etc/resolv.conf` )
5. Check that name resolution works with other DNS server (`nslookup google.com 4.2.2.2`)
6. You can use `nameserver 4.2.2.2` in your `/etc/resolv.conf` , if you want just name resolution working aka pinging any site by name.
7. Share your bind `named.conf`, by the way, it must work out of the box as caching server.

Comment: After trying netstat -rn I found that I lacked a 127.0.0.1 destination and many of the gateways are 0.0.0.0 rather than *.  Is this a problem?

Comment: Have you pinged 4.2.2.2?

Comment: ping 4.2.2.2 was sucessful.  I'll put the output in an edit above.

Comment: so now show your `/etc/resolv.conf` and add there `nameserver 127.0.0.1`

Comment: resolv.conf has been added above as well as nameserver.

Comment: Do it like that: ` nameserver 127.0.0.1 nameserver 4.2.2.2 `

Comment: I mean, delete everything, except these two lines

Comment: as such? thanks.  feel free to do your own edits.

Comment: yes, now you can check dns, show output of ` nslookup google.com `

Comment: great.  ive added the nslookup above.  can I use any of the IP's or do I need to use a particular one?

Comment: If you need just name resolution, you can use 4.2.2.2, But, if you are trying to setup bind, you have to config it =). 

 Take a look here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIND9ServerHowto

Comment: At this time your server (127.0.0.1) didn't respond query. It is either not started, or  misconfigured.

Comment: ok, thank you.  i'll work with the suggested link and respond in a few hours.

Comment: I investigated the unresponsiveness as per your suggesting.  It now responds properly to dig -x 127.0.0.1, however will not respond to digs or pings on example.com.  I placed more info above.

Comment: here are the links you requested.  http://pastebin.com/m6faff332   http://pastebin.com/m2cf78dc5 .  Continued thanks.

Comment: Do you have your dns server runing?) 
show ` cat /var/log/syslog | grep bind `
and try ` nslookup google.com 127.0.0.1 `

Comment: cat /var/log/syslog | grep bind is here http://pastebin.com/m75bd69e5 and I updated nslookup under Old Issues above.

Comment: What is 192.168.1.1? Your server IP?
` cat /etc/bind/db.233 `

Comment: hah, i was just wondering the same thing.  It's not the machine's net IP.  shouldn't it be the ISP's DNS?  here's db.233, http://pastebin.com/d352227a4

Comment: i just checked, 192.168.1.1 and 68.238.64.12 are my ISP's DNS servers

Comment: Yes, it can be ISP DNS. Your reverse zone file ` /etc/bind/db.233 ` is wrong, it should be like that http://pastebin.com/m2bb7ce6e . Corrcet it and show you ` /etc/bind/named.conf.local `

Comment: And do you ping 192.168.1.1 ? And show me ` nslookup google.com 192.168.1.1 ` If you dont ping it, change it in ` named.conf.options ` to 68.238.64.12 .

Comment: The nslookup looks the same as that above.  I placed the IP you gave (ISP's DNS?) in the named.conf.options.  A dig -x 127.0.0.1    request was still got an Answer: 1, however dig example.com yielded Answer: 0.  It should be noted that I have changed resolv.conf (alteration above) based on research and Alnitak's advice since I want an Authoritative DNS.

Comment: check 2 comments above: correct zone and give other config

Comment: Do you want me to return resolv.conf to its previous configuration (version 1)?  You can see the alteration above under my question if you look at "Old Issues" - "resolv.conf" - "version 2".  Thanks for the patience.

Comment: Your reverse zone file  /etc/bind/db.233  is wrong, it should be like that pastebin.com/m2bb7ce6e . Corrcet it and show you  /etc/bind/named.conf.local

Comment: db.233 has been altered and i have appended named.conf.local above

Comment: ok, i think i've got it.  once i'm sure i'll give  you the details. :)

Comment: okey.......................

Comment: so, your alteration to named.conf.local was the key to get the digs and pings to work locally (eg. "dig -x 127.0.0.1" and "ping 1.2.3.4").  If I add the machine's net IP to the resolv.conf, then I can dig and ping the site by name, but I believe that is only for a recursive server.  So the problem now is that the ISP's DNSs' aren't acknowledging my DNS.

Comment: When you buy a domain, you enter in a CP your nameserver address, so if youa have a domain-do it now. If you want reverse lookup working ( to domain name from IP (nslookup 1.1.1.1; Answer: domian.com )) you have to ask your ISP to config reverse zone from static IP you have bought, to your domain.

Comment: i transferred my ns address a few days ago.  If the system is in the described state, the next step would be talking to the ISP to config the reverse zone and i'd be done?  I had thought that would happen automatically based on the forwarders.

Comment: thanks for all the help.  I moved the last problem with another post: http://serverfault.com/questions/87650/authoritative-dns-will-not-respond-to-pings-or-digs-on-domain  I hope the internet gods bless your soul.

Answer (score 3):

You need to clarify for us what particular DNS function this server is supposed to be doing - in particular, is it:

1. recursive - offering global DNS lookups for your LAN
2. authoritative - serving data for a zone that you run
3. both - possible, but strongly recommended against for security reasons

**EDIT** now confirmed as authoritative.

Given the reported problems with `ping` it's likely that you've got an underlying network problem to solve first before we start worrying about the DNS server config, though.  Your original question is unclear though - you appear to be reporting three separate problems:

1. `ping example.com` times out
2. `ping 1.2.3.4` says "no host"
3. the DNS Server returns `SERVFAIL`

(1) and (2) don't make sense as reported - if anything I'd expect the errors to be the other way around.  Please supply (redacted) examples of the output of those two commands.

Once that's resolved, we can start to address (3) - the `SERVFAIL` error normally indicates misconfiguration rather than access control problems.  However I see that it's taking 4 seconds to produce that response - `SERVFAIL` can also indicate failure to reach an upstream DNS server which would be consistent with you having network problems.

Comment: It will be an authoritative dns.  The network issue seems possible.  I am currently running tests on the server at a dynamic IP before sending it to a colo facility.  The dns was hosted until about 3 days ago, but the new IP should have updated by now.

Comment: When you say "the server", do you mean the DNS server, an application server, or some box that's doing both?

Comment: It's both a DNS and an application server.  I understand that it is best to separate these, but that will have to wait for greater resources.  Also, I forgot to mention that 
"named-checkzone" came out "ok".  So I assume that the forward and reverse zone files are not the culprit.

Comment: please supply the ping output logs per my edit above

Comment: "ping example.com" outputs - "ping: unknown host example.com".   "ping @1.2.3.4" (local ip) outputs - "ping: unknown host @1.2.3.4".    "ping @1.2.3.4" (net ip) outputs - "ping: unknown host @1.2.3.4"   My method of obtaining a forwarding IP for my ISP's DNS may have been in error. I understood that I could use any DNS that is owned by my provider. Is there a more concise method? thank you for the extensive assistance.

Comment: please add it to the question - not in the comments

Comment: and ping doesn't use an '@', it's just 'ping 1.2.3.4'.  we also need to know how quickly the 'unknown host' error is returned

Comment: i removed the localhost nameserver as you suggested and the dig -x 127.0.0.1 are in keeping with what I would expect, 1's for Query and Answer, 0's for Authority and Additional.

Answer (score 0):

try putting a "recursion yes;" in your named.conf - this will allow your server to give you dns records out of it's control.

This should be in your "options" section.  I would also create an ACL limiting access to this feature.

```
acl homenet { 192.168.0.0/24; 127.0.0.0/8; };

options {
  recursion yes;
  allow-recursion { homenet; };
}
```

Comment: updated the answer to include where to include the recursion option.  Also removed the allow-clients as it is a "view" option that I use - instead use the allow-recursion option as I've put in the answer.

Comment: placing "recursion yes;" in named.conf results in a failed restart of bind9.  however I have placed the above code into named.conf.options and successfully restarted bind9.

Comment: I see your able to resolve domains outside of your control now so the recursion is working but it seems that you are configuring a local domain example.com that is not working.  I would guess a configuration issue in the zone file - if you "tail -f /var/log/messages" and restart the nameserver do you get any error messages?

Comment: "tail -f /var/log/messages" gave the same output before and after the restart.  after the restart I was still unable to ping example.com by its name and dig still results in "no servers could be reached".  Were you thinking of a different error test?

Answer (score 0):

"a DNS"?  DNS is a protocol.  This is like saying "I'd like an HTTP."

Could you describe whether you want a DNS authoritative server, secondary server, client, caching server, private root, DNSsec, etc?